# Apply a function to segments of a list

Tags: r, list, for-loop, tidyverse

I have two list, and from those I would like to find the averages between different combinations of elements. I would like to find the mean for the first 3 elements between the list as shown below. I would then like to find the mean for the next 3 elements between the list.

For example:
I would like to apply the `mean` function on the first set of elements in `l1`. Here I would like to find the mean between: `l1[[1]]` and `l2[[1]]`,
`l1[[1]]` and `l2[[2]]`,`l1[[1]]` and `l2[[3]]`

Then `l1[[2]]` and `l2[[1]]`, `l1[[2]]` and `l2[[2]]`, `l1[[2]]` and `l2[[3]]`

Finally `l1[[3]]` and `l2[[1]]`, `l1[[3]]` and `l2[[2]]`, `l1[[3]]` and `l2[[3]]`.

Followed by the next three pairs:
`l1[[4]]` and `l2[[4]]`, `l1[[4]]` and `l2[[2]]`,`l1[[5]]` and `l2[[6]]`

Then `l1[[5]]` and `l2[[4]]`, `l1[[5]]` and `l2[[5]]`, `l1[[5]]` and `l2[[6]]`

Finally `l1[[6]]` and `l2[[4]]`, `l1[6]]` and `l2[[5]]`, `l1[[6]]` and `l2[[6]]`.

```
l1 <- list(1,2,3,4,5,6)
l2 <- list(7,8,9,10,11,12)

mean(l1[[1]], l2[[1]])
mean(l1[[1]], l2[[2]])
mean(l1[[1]],l2[[3]])

mean(l1[[2]], l2[[1]])
mean(l1[[2]], l2[[2]])
mean(l1[[2]],l2[[3]])

mean(l1[[3]], l2[[1]])
mean(l1[[3]], l2[[2]])
mean(l1[[3]],l2[[3]])


mean(l1[[4]], l2[[4]])
mean(l1[[4]], l2[[5]])
mean(l1[[4]],l2[[6]])

mean(l1[[5]], l2[[4]])
mean(l1[[5]], l2[[5]])
mean(l1[[5]],l2[[6]])

mean(l1[[6]], l2[[4]])
mean(l1[[6]], l2[[5]])
mean(l1[[6]],l2[[6]])
```

In my actual list, I have an extensive number of elements in each list so a more autonomous method is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can try `Map` like below

```
Map(
    function(x, y) outer(unlist(x), unlist(y), `+`) / 2,
    split(l1, ceiling(seq_along(l1) / 3)),
    split(l2, ceiling(seq_along(l2) / 3))
)
```

which gives

```
$`1`
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  4.0  4.5  5.0
[2,]  4.5  5.0  5.5
[3,]  5.0  5.5  6.0

$`2`
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  7.0  7.5  8.0
[2,]  7.5  8.0  8.5
[3,]  8.0  8.5  9.0
```

Comment: Do you think you could walk me through how I might be able to modify this to fit my actual list? Is `x` and `y` the two splits? What does the `+` mean in the `outer` function?

Comment: @JohnHuang `x` and `y` correspond to splits from `l1` and `l2`, and `+` means sum of inputs in `outer`

Comment: If my list contained `raster` objects, and I wanted to use a function to get a similar result as with the matrices created in this example, would I simply change the `+` to the desired function? What would be the best way of going about it?

Comment: @JohnHuang Sorry that I am not familiar with `raster`

Comment: Well lets say it was just an object rather than just an number, how would I go about modifying the code?

Comment: @JohnHuang If you you have specific function for `FUN = ` in `outer`, you can try something like `outer(unlist(x), unlist(y), FUN  = Vectorize(function(p,q) {....}))`